# C#, Windows Forms application, DataGridView data binding

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to read data from an OPC server periodically and show them on a DataGridView. Here is the code for that:

```
using AutoMapper;
using OpcUaClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly OpcUaSetup opcUa;
    private readonly MapperConfiguration tagMapperConfig;
    private readonly IMapper tagMapper;
    private Timer timer;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        opcUa = new OpcUaSetup();

        tagMapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<OpcUaClient.Models.OpcUaTagModel, Models.TagModel>();
        });

        tagMapper = tagMapperConfig.CreateMapper();
    }


    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        opcUa.ReadTags(opcUa.Tags);
        dgv_TagsTable.DataSource = tagMapper?.Map<List<OpcUaClient.Models.OpcUaTagModel>, BindingList<Models.TagModel>>(opcUa.Tags);
        StartTagUpdateTimer();
    }

    private void StartTagUpdateTimer()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            UpdateTags_1();
            //UpdateTags_2();
            //UpdateTags_3();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateTags_1()
    {
        opcUa.ReadTags(opcUa.Tags);
        //dgv_TagsTable.Update();
        //dgv_TagsTable.Refresh();

    }

    private void UpdateTags_2()
    {
        opcUa.ReadTags(opcUa.Tags);
        dgv_TagsTable.DataSource = tagMapper?.Map<List<OpcUaClient.Models.OpcUaTagModel>, BindingList<Models.TagModel>>(opcUa.Tags);


    }

    private void UpdateTags_3()
    {
        opcUa.ReadTags(opcUa.Tags);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_TagsTable.Rows)
        {
            string nameInDataGridView = row.Cells["Name"].Value?.ToString();

            var matchingItem = opcUa.Tags.Items
                .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == nameInDataGridView);

            row.Cells["Value"].Value = matchingItem?.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Like it is shown in the code, there is a timer with a 1000-millisecond interval, which calls one of the three methods for updating data on the DataGridView (dgv_TagsTable).

Regarding UpdateTags_1, it does not work as expected. Since dgv_TagsTable.DataSource is bound to OpcUa.Tags, I expect when OpcUa.Tags is updated, dgv_TagsTable should automatically update as well. However, it does not update even with the Update and Refresh methods that are commented in the code. The first question is why?

Regarding UpdateTags_2, it works well. But, It updates the entire table itself, so scrolling or selectings or other user interactiocns will be refreshed too. On UpdateTags_3, this issue is resolved, and only the contents of the specified cells are updated. However, since there is a foreach loop running and a massive tag list, it takes a while to update dgv_TagsTable and blocks it while updating. The question here is how to update the cell contents only (and not the entire table) and at the same time be efficient, so the update will not take so long?